# Get lines of text between two line numbers inside txt file

Tags: php, file, slice

My goal is to get every line of text from text line number 10 to number 15.

text file :

> [image]

my code :

```
$file = fopen('no_list.txt', 'r');
while ((feof ($file) === false) )
{
    $i=1;
    while ((feof ($file) === false) && $i<10 && $i<15 )
    {
        fgets($file);
        $i++;
    }
    $splitdata = fgets($file);
    echo $splitdata;
}
fclose($file);
```

The code only returns the data from line 15. Any suggestion what am I missing from my code? or any other solution to do it ?

Comment: For best  efficiency, you would read `seek` to the first desired line, then if you are doing an loop, break your loop after you echo'ed your last desired line of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read your text file into an array and filter out the lines you need:

```
<?php

$lines = file('test.txt');
$start = 10;
$end = 15;

for($i = $start-1; $i<=$end-1; $i++) {
    $store[] = $lines[$i];
}
```

Array `$store` contains an element for each line that you selected to filter, in between `$start` and `$end`;

Answer (score 0):

Easier to read the file into an array and slice off what you want:

```
$splitdata = array_slice(file('no_list.txt'), 9, 6);
```

`$splitdata` will be an array so loop or `implode` it to `echo`:

```
echo implode(', ', $splitdata);
```